# Common word for level and area

Tags: single-word-requests, australian-english

Suppose that a building is divided in levels (floors) which are further divided in areas.

How would you them both with one word? (preferably in Australian English)

Best word I could think of so far is "location" and "zone". Perhaps there is a commonly used term for this (I'm not a native English speaker).

Comment: *Floorspace*, maybe?

Comment: Can you include a sample sentence please?  I'm struggling to think of a context where you'd want to use this.

Comment: FWIW, my workplace does use the term "zone" for this.  I thought it was a company-specific thing, but I guess it could work elsewhere.

Comment: You might refer to the areas as _suites_. But that generally implies that each area is unique and doesn't belong to any other. At that point, you also get the level/floor number by the suite number. So, Ste. 130 is on the first/ground floor, 230 is on the second, etc.

Comment: It's going to depend on what the areas delineate.

Comment: *Zone* is often used to refer to the divisions of building's utility services, security management, and climate control. It's already overworked. I would try to steer clear of it in other senses.

Comment: If you want to sound all cool like a spy movie, you could call them "sectors".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think really have a particular word for this in Australia, maybe **section**.

For example in a department store you could hear this "You will find bedding on level 4 in the homewares **section**"

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. It would be great if you could add some references to back up your answer.